# Copying data with format from one excel to another using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I tried copying data from one excel sheet to another, but my data is getting trimmed and the format is not the same as the copied. I need the exact format to be copied, as I have to reuse the cell contents to insert into DB.

The code to copy looks like this:

```
String cell = excelSheet.getCell(col, r).getContents().trim();
```

How to copy the cells keeping the original cell format?

Comment: Am I being stupid or are you just not reading the part of the code that says trim()

Comment: trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string

Comment: I don't get it - you're complaining that the data is trimmed and yet you are using the trim() function?